# PHP Mailer - attachment file not opening (when I attach using mobile browser)

Tags: android, html, email, mobile, phpmailer

I have one PHP page to send email with attachment (career form).
I have received Emails with attachment correctly on (**windows Chrome** Browser).

Attachment not opening **file size: 0Bytes**  when I using **Android mobile - chrome** Browser
(Note: Mail received with Attachment from mobile - but attachment not support)

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<form type="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="attachment">
    <button name="submit" type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
extract($_POST);

$to="example@email.com";
$msg="email body";

require 'include/PHPMailer_master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'include/PHPMailer_master/src/SMTP.php';
require 'include/PHPMailer_master/src/Exception.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);

enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                        
    $mail->isSMTP();                                   
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.siteprotect.com'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;               
    $mail->Username = 'example@email.com';          
    $mail->Password = 'password';                   
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                       
    $mail->Port = 587;                                  

    $mail->setFrom('example@email.com');
    $mail->addAddress($to);     

    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], 
$_FILES['attachment']['name'] );      

    $mail->isHTML(true);   
    $mail->Subject = 'RESUME - Sales Engineer (from website careers page)';
    $mail->Body    = $msg;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    $mail->send();
    echo '<script>alert("Message has been sent");</script>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<script>alert("Message not sent");</script>';
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
}
```

Comment: Code? Example message structure?

Comment: Please check Edited post

Comment: In php 9th line "enables exceptions" is a comment line above the try block

Comment: You are not handling the upload and attachment correctly. Look at the examples provided with PHPMailer.